# How to attach id to ng-model dynamically

Tags: c#, html, angularjs

```
<select class="form-control" select-multiple-picker multiple data-max-options="2" ng-model="userDetails.ClinicalRoles" name="createUserSelectClinicalRoles" id="createUserSelectClinicalRoles">
    <option ng-repeat="role in clinicalRole" value="{{role.Description}}">{{role.Description}}</option>
</select>
```

Here I am getting data from server to  list, I am only showing `{{role.Description}}` to user, but when I submit I need to attach `role.id` and `role.Description` to `ng-Model` for calling API.

Comment: Do you want to say that you will select description but you need id for that particular description when you will select?

Comment: yes, That id i need to attach to ng-Model

Comment: I need id, Description to bind to ng-Model

Comment: Okay for that, you need to use ng-options that I have explained in the answer. That is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with ng-options and select as: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ng-repeat for that. Use ng-options instead.

Try this-

```
<select class="form-control" select-multiple-picker multiple data-max-options="2" ng-model="userDetails.ClinicalRoles" name="createUserSelectClinicalRoles" id="createUserSelectClinicalRoles"
ng-options="role.id as role.Description for role in clinicalRole">                
</select>
```

If you want to select both at a time. Then you can use a trick. Add ng-change attribute in select and pass that selected role.id as it's model in a function.

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" select-multiple-picker multiple data-max-options="2" ng-model="userDetails.ClinicalRoles" name="createUserSelectClinicalRoles" id="createUserSelectClinicalRoles"
ng-options="role.id as role.Description for role in clinicalRole" 
ng-change="setDescription(role)">                
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.lastSelectedDesc = {};
$scope.setDescription(role){
   $scope.lastSelectedDesc = role;
}
```

Simply do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can save complete object in ng-model instead of single property.

HTML :-

```
<div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="Ctrl" style="margin-top:40px">
        <div>
            <select class="form-control" id="Region" data-ng-model="selectedValue" data-ng-options="value.Desc for value  in values track by value.id">
                <option value=''>Select</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            Selected Option Label : {{selectedValue.label}}<hr/>
            Selected Option Id : {{selectedValue.id}}<hr/>
            Selected Option Desc : {{selectedValue.Desc}}<hr />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript :-

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

           var IsApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

            IsApp.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
                $scope.values = [{
                    id: 1,
                    label: 'aLabel',
                    Desc: 'Desc-aLabel'
                }, {
                    id: 2,
                    label: 'bLabel',
                    Desc: 'Desc-bLabel'
                }];
            });// End of controller
        </script>
```

While submitting you can pass *selectedValue.id* and *selectedValue.Desc*.